I've built a different GCC version than the system's, and now get "undefined reference"s and "DSO missing from command-line"
I've built GCC 14.2.0 from sources, on an Oracle GNU/Linux 9.4 machine (whose distribution compiler is GCC 11.4.1). The build went fine; but when I now try to use it to build some library, I get:
/usr/bin/ld: /home/joeusr/opt/gtest/lib64/libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o): undefined
reference to symbol '_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIwSt11char_traitsIwESaIwEE10_M_disposeEv@@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/joeuser/opt/versions/gcc/14.2.0/lib/../lib64/libstdc++.so.6:
error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

(lines broken for readability)
What/who is at fault, and when can do to overcome that?
Additional information:
My GCC build configuration command was:
./configure --disable-ada --disable-gnat --disable-fortran 
--disable-bootstrap --disable-multilib  --disable-bootstrap 
--without-isl --enable-languages=c,c++  --prefix=$HOME/opt/versions/gcc/14.2.0 
--with-gmp=$HOME/opt/gmp  --with-mpfr=$HOME/opt/mpfr --with-mpc=$HOME/opt/mpc


When i build gcc from source i usually add the compiler's libs path to the begining of the LD_LIBRARY_PATH so the system can find libstdc++ and libgcc .... this solves the missing symbols, never seen the DSO thing before, but i bet it cannot find libstdc++

@AhmedAEK: You mean, something like LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/joeuser/opt/versions/gcc/14.2.0/lib64/ ?

Yes, that. It would be helpful to go over the build and gcc install steps too, the process is usually smooth, you configure passing the needed params like disabling multibuild and the install prefix then make then make install

Okay ... how are you building this ? I see /usr/bin/ld .. can you try using g++ directly to build a simple script ? Try it with statically linked libstdc++ and libgcc ... it might be your build system using the base system libraries over the new ones, i usually also add the bin folder to the start of the PATH as well as set CC and CXX to point to the absolute path of the new gcc and g++ directly.

Following the advice of @AhmedAEK, I went "all the way" trying to adapt to the new compiler. First, I set environment variables as follows:
export GCC_VERSION=14.2.0
export GCC_PLATFORM=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
export GCC_BASE_DIR=$HOME/opt/versions/gcc/${GCC_VERSION}
export COMPILER_PATH=$GCC_BASE_DIR/bin
export PATH="${COMPILER_PATH}:${PATH}"
export CC=${COMPILER_PATH}/gcc
export CXX=${COMPILER_PATH}/g++
export LIBRARY_PATH=${GCC_BASE_DIR}/lib64:${GCC_BASE_DIR}/lib:${LIBRARY_PATH}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${GCC_BASE_DIR}/lib64:${GCC_BASE_DIR}/lib:${LIBRARY_PATH}
export C_INCLUDE_PATH="${GCC_BASE_DIR}/lib/gcc/${GCC_PLATFORM}/${GCC_VERSION}/include:${GCC_BASE_DIR}/include:${C_INCLUDE_PATH}"
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH="${GCC_BASE_DIR}/lib/gcc/${GCC_PLATFORM}/${GCC_VERSION}/include:${GCC_BASE_DIR}/include/c++:${C_INCLUDE_PATH}:${CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH}"

So - executables, include directories, libraries - perhaps also some that I'm not aware of.
I also made sure to rebuild my project's dependency library (libgtest) with these environment variables.
After having done that - my build succeeded.
It's possible that just setting CXX and LD_LIBRARY_PATH, and rebuilding the dependcy library would have sufficed.

It's hard to know from information you've provided, but (to expand a little on AhmedAEK's comment) a possible explanation is that config of the gcc you're building causes the linker to find an incorrect version of libstdc++ or libgcc libraries.  There is usually a tight coupling between versions of gcc and versions of libstdc++ or libgcc that need to be linked with.   It is possible that the version of gcc you are building, by default, links against libraries already installed on your system rather than the versions needed - and your tweaks of environment variables manage to correct that.
